# Java - Convert/Copy all values of String[] array into ArrayList<BigInteger>

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, collections

Is it possible to copy and/or convert all values from `String[]` array into an `ArrayList<BigInteger>` in one just line?

Like this:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(StringArray);
```

My current source code had no problem but i'm finding a way (if there is) to make it more efficient.

```
List<BigInteger> Data = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    for (String current : StringArray) //Gets values from array String[] unsorted
       Data.add(new BigInteger(current)); //Each string will be added in the list
```

My logic to achieve my goal is to iterate through entire array of `String[]` then get each Strings and add every String into the `List<BigInteger>`

Comment: If you need convert all the `String` to `BigInteger`, the method in your question is the most efficient way to do that. if you only need convert some, you can use `Stream` instead. Sine `Stream` is lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Stream`s:

```
List<BigInteger> data = Arrays.stream(StringArray).map(BigInteger::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you could shortcut :

```
List<BigInteger> data = Arrays.stream(strings)
                               .map(BigInteger::new)
                               .collect(toList());
```